# animation bullets so that they come after one an other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on an rails app in which I have design like show in the image
There are four points, I want them to come one after an other.
(like first point appears, than second point and so on)

[image: this image]

I never had worked like this, So I don't know how to do this.

I had seen some tutorials about animation, all I found is like moving box, changing colors.

Kindly guide me towards right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with something like stagger.css

http://digitalfio.github.io/Stagger.css/

Include the css file in your `<head>`, apply the animation classes to each div then add a timing class to each div in the form of an underscore followed by an incrementing number - e.g.

```
<div class="animated slideIn _1"></div>
<div class="animated slideIn _2"></div>
<div class="animated slideIn _3"></div>
<div class="animated slideIn _4"></div>
```

so you get something like this: http://output.jsbin.com/cusuz/4

Answer (score 0):

Increase your div width using javascript step by step

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
    <img src="yourimage" />
</div>
```

Comment: I am not finding words to explain this.
but I want animation not this